# Emacs + imaxima: "Symbol's function definition is void: defun*" [solved]

Tags: maxima

I have maxima 5.44.0 installed on my machine (Manjaro Linux) and it runs fine in a shell, and in Emacs 27.1 when I launch M-x maxima.
I've added

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/maxima/")  
(autoload 'maxima-mode "maxima" "Maxima mode" t)  
(autoload 'imaxima "imaxima" "Frontend for maxima with Image support" t)  
(autoload 'maxima "maxima" "Maxima interaction" t)  
(autoload 'imath-mode "imath" "Imath mode for math formula input" t)  
(setq imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag t)  
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ma[cx]\\'" . maxima-mode))
```

to my .emacs file.

But when in Emacs I launch M-x imaxima I get the error message "Symbol's function definition is void: defun*"
Has someone encountered this problem and has an example of a working configuration?

**EDIT**

My `imaxima.el` and `imath.el` files call `defun*`, which was defined in `cl.el`, but Emacs 27.1 has replaced `cl.el` with `cl-lib.el`, which replaces `defun*` with `cl-defun`. The updated `*.el` files are
[imath.el](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/41a26a76d98a6769c4c886bf1883109edc93fb92/tree/interfaces/emacs/imaxima/imath.el) and [imaxima.el](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/41a26a76d98a6769c4c886bf1883109edc93fb92/tree/interfaces/emacs/imaxima/imaxima.el)
Now I can start imaxima, I get a "Latex error", but that's another matter :)

Comment: This is no doubt a duplicate. Hopefully someone will find the dup and close this question, if so. You need to `require` the library that defined `defun*` (which is maybe `cl-lib.el`). It's probably enough to require it a byte-compile time: `eval-when-compile`.

Comment: @Drew, cl-lib.el is required by imaxima.el.

Comment: Looks like it's `cl.el` that defines macro `defun*`. (Well, actually it's `cl-macro.el` that defines it.)

Comment: @Drew, cl.el is obsolete in Emacs 27.1. And this is the problem. I'm going to edit my question. I thank you for your hint!

Comment: Obsolete doesn't mean it doesn't work, and it doesn't mean you can't use it. To use it, just require it for byte-compiling.